# RemainingDays not returning correct count

Tags: c#

In this sample I am trying to get the RemainingDays from two dates. One of the day is the next day and the other is two days from now. I am using dateTime.now and getting

Code

```
   int? RemainingDays = null;
   DateTime? EndDateTest1 = new DateTime(2022, 5, 11);
   RemainingDays = ( EndDateTest1.Value - DateTime.Now ).Days;
```

Current Output

```
0
1
```

Thinking it should be

```
1
2
```

Working sample

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bYcLeZ

Comment: You probably ought to be using `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: `EndDateTest1` is at 12:00AM (since you didn't specify the time.  `DateTime.Now` will include the time component, so unless the current time is exactly 12:00AM on the 10th, it will be less than 24 hours.

Comment: Why not use: RemainingDays = ( EndDateTest1.Value.Day - DateTime.Now.Day ); RemainingDays = (EndDateTest2.Value.Day - DateTime.Now.Day); ?

Comment: you can also use the `ToShortDateString` - as follows: `RemainingDays = (EndDateTest2.Value - Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())).Days;` - [dotnetfiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YvhJXq)

Comment: If duplicate (that is identical to accepted answer) is not enough, please review results of search like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+days+between+2+dates  and [edit] the post to clarify how it is different so it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to resolve by only getting date portion via

```
 RemainingDays = ( EndDateTest1.Value - DateTime.Now.Date ).Days;
```

The .Date ending of a date/time field will truncate any time portion for you.

Comment: Alternative to `DateTime.Now.Date` can be `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: @gunr2171, but if you have other fields that are date/time based, you can still use the .Date extension on those too. :)

Answer (score 3):

A `DateTime` is not a date, but, as the name implies, a *date* and a *time*.

If you initialize a `DateTime` with only a date, the time will be 00:00:00.

The time of `DateTime.Now()` *will* actually have a value, so when you subtract that from your `EndDateTest1`, the result will actually be *less* than the full number of days you expect. If you run this around 8 P.M., the result of the subtraction is 4 **hours**, which is, indeed, 0 days.

Comment: Bonus points: there's now a [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) type in .Net 6

Comment: @gunr2171, .Date extension of a DateTime field has been around like forever.